# How do I pass static_cast<T> as a function?

Tags: c++11, functor, static-cast

I have a type `A` that's designed to be implicitly casted to type `B`.  Here's an example case I'd like to use it in:

```
// Current implementation:
std::transform(vec_of_a.begin(), vec_of_a.end(), std::back_inserter(vec_of_b),
               [](const A& a) -> B { return a; });  // Thanks, Kerrek SB.

// Ideal implementation - Won't compile, expected '(' after 'static_cast'.
std::transform(vec_of_a.begin(), vec_of_a.end(), std::back_inserter(vec_of_b),
               static_cast<B>);
```

What can I do to make the latter option compile?

Comment: How about: `std::vector<B> vec_of_b(vec_of_a.begin(), vec_of_a.end());`?

Comment: @KerrekSB That's a good point, and it solves my particular problem.  But I'd still like to know the cleanest way to pass static_cast<B> around as a function.

Comment: `[](const A & x) -> B { return x; }`

Comment: @KerrekSB Then, there's no way to pass `static_cast<B>`?  If you put that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: There's no way to treat `static_cast<B>` as a function, even though it uses function syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static_cast<B>`, while it is invoked with function-call syntax cannot be passed like other callable things. E.g., there's no way to use `&` to get a function pointer to it.

You can use a short little lambda to achieve something similar to passing a function pointer to `static_cast<B>`, as you do in your current implementation:

```
std::transform(vec_of_a.begin(), vec_of_a.end(), std::back_inserter(vec_of_b),
               [](const A& a) -> B { return a; });
```

Another option--in this particular case--would be to construct a `vector<B>` from the `vector<A>`:

```
std::vector<B> vec_of_b(vec_of_a.begin(), vec_of_a.end());
```

(This answer is a summary of the comments on both the question and [bipll's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2749717/bipll) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39479868/2392683).)

Answer (score 2):

Build a functor enclosing `static_cast`:

```
template <typename T>
struct StaticCast
{
    template <typename U>
    T operator()(const U& rhs)
    {
        return static_cast<T>(rhs);
    }
};
```

With this, you can call `std::transform`:

```
std::transform(vec_of_a.begin(), vec_of_a.end(), std::back_inserter(vec_of_b), StaticCast<b>());
```

It can be used in the case the output vector is already defined in place of the lambda shown in comments. If not, prefer the constructor mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39653623/1507014)**.

This functor version is compliant with C++98 if needed -- even if OP is tagged `C++11`, it may be worthy to note this point.

** Note that with this particular constructor, a warning C4244 is raised with VS compiler (tested with VS2017).

Answer (score -3):

Yes, that's the way anonymous functions work in C++, and `static_cast` is not a function so you cannot pass its address as the mapped function. You'll have to deal with it.

You cannot use a constructor either.

Comment: This answer would be better if it expanded on "You'll have to deal with it" by discussing ways to deal with it. A number of ways have been mentioned in the comments on the question already.

Comment: @chwarr, sure, so what? Do I have to add "A number of ways have been mentioned in the comments on the question already" to my answer? Do I need to copypaste them?

Comment: Yes, adding the actual solutions (copy/paste) is the way to go. Comments aren't durable and can be deleted in the future. With answers, there's at least history and edit review queues.